# fabric UI: Panel onDismiss called when try to enter some text in the Dialog

Tags: dialog, panel, office-ui-fabric

I first opened a panel, then opened a dialog to input some info, but the dialog and panel will close whenever I start typing in the dialog.

I added `onOuterClick={() => { }}` to Panel, then it doesn't allow me to type anything.

my code looks like

```
  <Panel
    isOpen={props.isOpen}
    isHiddenOnDismiss={true}
    onDismiss={onDismiss}
    type={PanelType.large}
    closeButtonAriaLabel="Close"
    headerText={detailHeader}
    className={extraClass}
    onOuterClick={() => { }} >
```

the Panel is
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/examples/panel?view=office-ui-fabric-react-latest

anyway to solve this issue?